# Remote login with ColdFusion

Tags: curl, coldfusion, cfhttp

I'm working on an application that has a 'login' for clients to connect to their webmail or other services that are hosted by another company on a remote server.

What is the best way to provide the login on the site I'm developing and get users verified before passing them on to the other site where their other services can be found?

I'm using CF9 in a shared hosting environment. The other services are running in a PHP environment. Is there a tutorial I haven't found on this sort of thing?

Thank you in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you're attempting to do and the answer is no, you can't do that unfortunately (sorry I know that's not the answer you're looking for).

So, for example, you could write a form, that lets the user put in their login information, and then you log them into ebay automatically.

The issue here is that in order to do that login process, the *server* would be the client that is logging in, not the user (meaning you couldn't log in two users of your site at the same time, because the server would be logged into the session with ebay as either one user or the other).

Now, you might decide even that is okay as long as you can log in and out to perform functions, for example, an auto-bidding system for ebay.  The issue you'l run into is that 1) the site you're logging into will probably not like it, easily detect it, and stop you and 2) the http session won't be maintained like a real browser and is easily blocked, for example, no javascript would run.

The tags you would use are `<cfhttp>` - using this, you can get pages and post form values as if the server itself was making those requests.  -with the above considerations of course

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. Couple questions though, how is it that I can log in to facebook from another site? Would I be able to call the login page of the other site in my page instead? Does that make sense? Or is that the same thing as above? I just want a user to be able to log into their webmail from my site and upon successful login, pass them off to their webmail.

Comment: Sorry, I just re-read your comments about the `<cfhttp>` tag. To be clear, you're saying that anytime I call a page or it's components with `<cfhttp>` that my *server* is logging in and not my user and therefore when the user does navigate to the page they just logged in to, they will get bounced out because they're not the one that's actually logged in...

Comment: That's correct - the server is logged in with <cfhttp>, not the user :)

Comment: To address the facebook question, this is done with actual API's supplied by facebook - and the user is actually logging in and submitting information directly to facebook, not to you.  If you inspect the pop up you'll see.  The way this single sign on works is that facebook then sends you information on the user after they log into the facebook authorization - but you never control the actual log in or ever see the user's login information.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Sorry for dragging this out like that. Your info not only helped me understand but also be able to put it into a context my client can understand. Double win for me...

Comment: No problem at all, If I didn't want to do it, I wouldn't - like all programmers, I can be pretty lazy.  :)    (haven't we all at written a script to do nothing more than make our jobs easier when manual data editing or similar would have been about as equally as fast?  haha)

Answer (score 0):

can you direct your client on your CF site to post the credentials directly to PHP side?  That'd be easiest.  Otherwise you'll need to use use cfhttp or webservice to communivate with the PHP site, and agree on a one-time-only token, then forward the client using that key in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

I am still unclear on what you're trying to achieve, but it sounds like OAuth might be something to look into.

Comment: My goal: User is on my site. My site has a username and password form. They enter their info and click submit. Info is submitted to third party site and either sends back an error (which I display) or logs the user in and redirects them to that site. Sorry for being unclear.